# server side of rmi hangs

Tags: java, client-server, rmi

I have been able to setup an rmi server and call it successfully with no problem in my debugging but when I am trying to use it in a 'real case' it hangs. My real case is a plugin for a 3rd party application where it makes calls to my server application. My client actually starts the server side by starting a new process which puts the object in the registry.  My client then calls the stub and calls a method in it but it only gets so far then stops. If I then kill my client the server will continue. Its as if the client side is holding onto something that the server side needs but they are running in separate jvm's so I can't work out what it would be. I wouldnt have thought what the client was doing would have any affect?
As I said the debugging of this works, ie the client starts the server process and then calls to the server are ok. I'm not running it with a security policy as its only a demo for now but not sure if thats an issue? Its all running on one machine, not distributed in any way.
The client is in 1.6 whereas the server is 1.7, again, is that a problem?
I was wondering if anybody has had similar problems or can recommend another way to do what I'm trying to besides RMI. Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: I suggest that your server is doing some console I/O in the remote method and you aren't reading it in the process that started it.

Comment: i found the cause and nothing to do with rmi. the server side is doing some logging to a file which hangs on an IO function. although im still not completely sure why this is happening as each application is in its own jvm and they are not accessing the same files